# Jenkins groovy security problems

Tags: security, jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I am trying to get all the files matching a filter. Here is my code:

```
import static groovy.io.FileType.FILES
node {
    try{

        stage('get files')
        new File('.').eachFileRecurse(FILES) {
                if(it.name.endsWith('.nuspec')) {
                    echo it.Name
                }
            }
    }catch(err) {
        echo 'Err: Incremental Build failed with Error: ' + err.toString()
    }finally { 

    }
```

I get the following error:

```
Err: Incremental Build failed with Error: org.jenkinsci.plugins.scriptsecurity.sandbox.RejectedAccessException: Scripts not permitted to use new java.io.File java.lang.String
```

I've checked there are No pending script approvals.
I can't find any option to disable sandboxing.

The script runs fine when I try it in the script console. 
How do I allow the script to run on my builds?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/pipeline-utility-steps/#findfiles-find-files-in-the-workspace

```
def files = findFiles(glob: '**/*.nuspec') 
echo "${files[0].name} ${files[0].path} ${files[0].directory} ${files[0].length} ${files[0].lastModified}"
```